# Tag the Altruist in comments on a bounty question

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, bounty

This question was asked 8 months ago: [C# Excel Interop - Suppress 'Publishing' dialog when invoking Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010560/c-sharp-excel-interop-suppress-publishing-dialog-when-invoking-worksheet-exp)

A guy (Michael Brandon Morris) recently put a Bounty on it, however when I try and tag him in a comment it doesn't work (his name in intellisense isn't shown). I can tag the other commentors like SimonM, cyboashu and lokusking. Just *not* the OP or the bounty awarder.

Just wondering if this is by design and/or if others agree it'd be good to be able alert the person who has placed the bounty.

Or maybe the answer is simply user education, I've answered [a fair few bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/359998/stackoverflow-top-bounty-hunters)... but without tagging the bounty awarder I'm unsure if he will get alerted?

Comment: The bounty sponsor ought to pay attention to the comments.  That needs to get started you actually posting a comment, you didn't yet.  In the unlikely case he doesn't know that paying attention would be wise you could alert him by posting a comment to one of his other posts.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant since none of the guys tagged the bounty awarder (well they cant as per this question) and he (Michael) hasn't responded I'm not sure. He was last seen 16 hours ago so I am not sure if he has seen the comments. Given your breathtaking Bounty experience do you know if by just writing a comment Michael will see it in his alerts? Thanks

Comment: Fairly sure he won't get an inbox alert.  Hard to see, bounty givers are universally unresponsive to comments, they are shopping for a helpdesk answer.

Comment: Someone who sets a bounty on a question *is* notifiable with a comment `@`-reply. I'm not sure if they're notified without that, and it may not offer auto-completion, but they certainly get notified if you ping their user name. This is [semi-documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: As long as they are in the revision history, they can be pinged.

Comment: The points are yours @Braiam if you can show how, until then dont go editing this question, unless you're in the top #25 bounty hunters or have answered at least one Bounty. Sorry to seem harsh, replying to them wasn't the question, tagging them was. Both are uncertain at the moment but *tagging* leads to a feature improvement, where as *replying* does not.

Comment: Dude confirmed he was notified like half an hour ago.

Comment: Thanks @Renan, *no one knew that*, when he confirms which message alerted him then this Q is answered.

Comment: Do you know which one @Renan? I'd be grateful for an answer

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "tagging" the bounty awarder. Do you simply mean the auto-completion? If so, this ought to be a [meta-tag:feature-request].